# AzerothCore Rapberry Pi 4b: Modules not loading, error saying "Table `command` contains data for non-existant command"

Tags: azerothcore

I have setup AzerothCore on my Raspberry Pi 4B running Ubuntu through the Bash setup, and it is working fine. Trying to setup modules however, I can't seem to make them work. I put files into `azerothcore-wotlk/modules`, run CMake in terminal via `cmake azerothcore-wotlk` and run the SQL queries in the database. However, they refuse to load, and I recieve errors upon starting the server that say:

```
Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'xp'. Skipped.
Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'xp enable'. Skipped.
Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'xp disable'. Skipped.
Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'xp set'. Skipped.
Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'xp view'. Skipped.
Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'xp default'. Skipped.
Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'chata'. Skipped.
Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'chath'. Skipped.
Table `command` contains data for non-existant command 'chat'. Skipped.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn on autoupdater in worldserver.conf: `Updates.EnableDatabases = 7`
clear `version_db_world` table
and restart server
It must apply all uptates to your database when server starts.

If after that the errors repeat or the updater does not work, run db_assembler with parameter 5. It's a little longer, but it's guaranteed to fill everything you need into the database.

Comment: I followed what you said, woldserver.conf had EnableDatabases set to 7 by default, version_db_world was clear, and ran db_assembler with parameter 5, but still getting the same result. Is it possible i messed up with CMake? i am just running ```cmake azerothcore-wotlk``` and letting it run and then querying the sql as per the module. Am i missing a step?

Comment: Cmake.... May be. 
After pressing "Configure" have you fixed CMAKE_INSTALL_PATH and pressed "Configure" once again?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by configuring... in terminal i run "cmake azerothcore-wotlk" and let it run, it says it puts the build files in /ryan/home/. Is there a way to have it configure? I know azerothcore site shows instructions for a gui for cmake, is there a way to get that on a raspberry pi?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, turns out out i was trying to run cmake and other commands seperately, and ended up breaking things. I started from scratch and updated the server properly after adding a module and everything is working now.